Merging two different github repo
I have developed a Movie Review app in which the front-end was developed using ReactJS and Backend was developed using Springboot. But when i try to upload the code to github, i can only upload them as separate repo's.Here's is the pic of those two repo
As I'm a complete begineer in git/github i uploaded them by seeing tutorials on youtube. but i can't find any idea on how to merge them in single file name Moview Review app.

A git repository is not a single file.

@aled what do you mean?

How is this related to the Java Language (itself)? Why that tag? BTW a Git repository is a whole directory tree (collection of files) and its history, not a single file (regarding "how to merge them in single file")

Combine both on them in single project-folder on your machine then run git init and upload as single repo.

But then you don’t retain the git history.

To do this, follow these steps
1-Create a New Repository
First, create a new repository on GitHub where you will combine both projects. You can name it something like movie-review-app.
2-Clone the New Repository Locally
Open your terminal or command prompt and clone the new empty repository to your local machine.
git clone https://github.com/your-username/movie-review-app.git
cd movie-review-app

3-Add the Frontend and Backend Repositories
You need to add both the frontend and backend repositories as remotes in this new repository.
git remote add frontend https://github.com/your-username/frontend-repo.git

git remote add backend https://github.com/your-username/backend-repo.git

‍‍‍‍‍‍
4-Fetch and Merge the Frontend Repository
Fetch the contents of the frontend repository and merge them into your new repository.
git fetch frontend

Create a directory for the frontend code and checkout the frontend branch
mkdir frontend
git worktree add frontend frontend/main
cd frontend
git checkout -b frontend main
cd ..

This will create a directory named frontend and place the frontend code there.
5-Fetch and Merge the Backend Repository
Similarly, fetch the contents of the backend repository and merge them into your new repository.
Commit and Push Changes
After adding both repositories, you need to commit these changes and push them to GitHub.
git add frontend backend
git commit -m "Add frontend and backend projects"

git push origin main

After completing these steps, your new repository will have the following directory structure:
movie-review-app/
  ├── frontend/
  │   ├── ... (ReactJS frontend files)
  └── backend/
      ├── ... (Spring Boot backend files)

